# Memory Management Command Line Arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am writing a simple program that takes the command line arguments and stores them into a char **.  I am trying to learn more about memory management but cannot get past this simple stumbling block.  My program is supposed to copy the command line argumetns into a dynamicly allocated char **.  However the first position in my array is always corrupter.  Below is the code and what it prints:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "test") ==0)
{
    test();
}
else
{
    char ** file_names = malloc(10);

    for(int i =0; i < argc-1; ++i)
    {
        file_names[i] = malloc(10);
        strcpy(file_names[i], argv[i+1]);

        printf("%s, %s\n", argv[i+1], file_names[i]);
    }

    printf("____________\n");

    for(int i =0; i < argc-1; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", file_names[i]);
    }
}
```

and the out come is:

```
what, what
test, test
again, again
wow, wow
____________
pK@??
test
again
wow
```

can someone please explain why this is happening?  Thanks

Comment: You most likely have *undefined behavior*, as for `file_names` you only allocate *ten bytes*, not space for ten pointers.

Comment: Can you explain how to allocate in bytes.  I follow what you are saying, just dont understand the solution.

Comment: Just refer answer section

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
char ** file_names = malloc(10);
```

is a bug. It attempts to allocate 10 bytes, which has nothing at all to do with how many bytes you need. Under-allocating and then overwriting gives you undefined behavior.

It should be something like:

```
char **file_names = malloc(argc * sizeof *file_names);
```

This computes the size of the allocation by multiplying the number of arguments (`argc`, if you don't want to store `argv[0]` then this should be `(argc - 1)`, of course) by the size of a character pointer, which is expressed as `sizeof *file_names`. Since `file_names` is of type `char * *`, the type of `*file_names` is `char *`, which is what you want. This is a general pattern, it can be applied very often and it lets you stop repeating the type name. It can protect you from errors.

For instance compare:

```
double *floats = malloc(1024 * sizeof(float));  /* BAD CODE */
```

and:

```
double *floats = malloc(1024 * sizeof *floats);
```

If you imagine that originally it was `float *floats` (as the naming suggests) then the first variant contains another under-allocation bug, while the second "survived" the change of types without error.

Then you need to check that it succeeded, before assuming it did.

Comment: Thank you.  Never knew about under allocating and overwriting.  Can you explain what you are doing with your second line.  what does "malloc(argc * sizeof *file_names)" do?

Comment: @user2455869: It allocates memory for argc elements of the size that `*file_names` has, which is `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @user2455869 What did you think `malloc(10)` meant? Surely it stands to reason that if you use more than you allocate, that can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You want to allocate the right amount of memory for `file_names`, probably more like:

```
char ** file_names = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (argc - 1));
```

Comment: But `(sizeof(char*) * argc)` if you want to copy all the arguments.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is asumming the executable file name wasn't needed as per the `for` loop.  But if so, then yes use `argc` not `argc - 1`

Comment: Ah yes, I missed his `argv[i+1]`.